# combining matrix by name

Tags: r

I have a set of matrix named `gof_1_1`, `gof_1_2`, ..... ,`gof_1_24`. I want to combine all of them in to one matrix along the columns. So am using the following code

```
do.call(cbind,mget(ls(pattern = paste("gof",1,"[0-9]",sep="_"), globalenv())))
```

It combines the matrix, but problem is they are not in an order. They go like this `gof_1_1` , `gof_1_11`, `gof_1_12`, ..... , `gof_1_19`, `gof_1_2`, `gof_1_21` and so on. So I edited the `ls()` as shown below

```
ls(pattern = paste("gof",1,"[0-9][0-9]",sep="_"),globalenv())
```

Now it's in order,But it starts from `gof_1_10`, to `gof_1_25`. Missing `gof_1_1` to `gof_1_9`. Any idea how to edit the above one to call all the matrix in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
do.call(cbind, mget(paste0("gof_1_", 1:24)))
```

Otherwise, something more complicated like:

```
mat.names    <- ls(pattern = paste("gof", 1, "[0-9]", sep="_"), globalenv())
mat.idx      <- as.integer(gsub(".*_", "", mat.names))
sorted.names <- mat.names[order(mat.idx)]
do.call(cbind, mget(sorted.names))
```

Comment: The first one is perfect.I think I made it complicated unnecessarily in the first place. Thank you for the simple solution @flodel

Answer (score 2):

an alternative to the paste0 function :

```
do.call(cbind, mget(sprintf("gof_1_%s", 1:24)))
```

Comment: Thank you @droopy for the alternative.