# change from string to objects

Tags: r, string, object

Let's say I have the following syntax:

```
a1 <- c(2,3)
a2 <- c(6,8)
a3 <- c(1,9)
```

And so, with the use of cbind the following shows:

```
cbind(a1,a2,a3)
     a1 a2 a3
[1,]  2  6  1
[2,]  3  8  9
```

However, the syntax:

```
cbind(paste('a',1:3,sep=''))
```

does not give me

```
     a1 a2 a3
[1,]  2  6  1
[2,]  3  8  9
```

What can I do to show the following with the function paste:

```
     a1 a2 a3
[1,]  2  6  1
[2,]  3  8  9
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here, and why not just use `data.frame` and assign the column names you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: constructing a data frame with many columns using paste()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644119/r-constructing-a-data-frame-with-many-columns-using-paste). Also, [R_combining matrix by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682851/r-combining-matrix-by-name/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to get multiple objects from strings, use `mget` to return the value in a `list` and then with `do.call` `cbind` it to `matrix`

```
do.call(cbind, mget(paste0('a',1:3)))
#     a1 a2 a3
#[1,]  2  6  1
#[2,]  3  8  9
```

Comment: I tried the following code: a1 <- c(2,3); a2 <- c(6,8); a3 <- c(1,9); a4 <- c(6,8); frame <- as.data.frame(cbind(a1,a2,a3,a4)); do.call(cbind, mget(paste0('frame$a',1:3))). However, it does not give the answer that I need. Why is that?

Comment: @Joseph It is not an object.  It is a column in an object 'frame'.  I am not sure about the need for this exercise.   You can do `lapply(paste0('frame$a',1:3), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it to object ,you can create a matrix:

```
m=matrix(c(a1,a2,a3),ncol=3)
colnames(m)=c("a1","a2","a3")
> m
     a1 a2 a3
[1,]  2  6  1
[2,]  3  8  9

> class(m)
[1] "matrix"
```